# beanshell script does not recognize a set of objects as a java.util.Collection

Tags: beanshell

I am using the following script to select an object from a set of input objects using an index.
It does not recognize that the input argument is a set of three values.
I assume I am doing something wrong in the line:

```
if(setOfObjects  instanceof java.util.Collection)


if(setOfObjects != null)
{
   if(setOfObjects  instanceof java.util.Collection)
   {
      object = setOfObjects.get(index);
      if (object instanceof fUML.Semantics.Classes.Kernel.Object_)
      {
         fUML.Semantics.Classes.Kernel.Reference r = new fUML.Semantics.Classes.Kernel.Reference(object.getOwner());
         r.setReferent(object);
         object = r;
      }
   }
   Else print(index);
   if(index == 1)
   {
      print("ok");
      object = setOfObjects;
   }
   else
   {
      print("failed");
      object = null;
   }
}
else
{
   object = null;
}
```

Comment: I would first check what this tells you: `print("setOfObjects is : " + setOfObjects.getClass().getName());`. Also capital Else? Not correct, unless BeanShell tolerates it.

Answer (score 0):

GaryMcM's approach is correct. The code worked correctly for me when I set `setOfObjects` as instance of `java.util.HashSet` in interpreter namespace, as below.

```
Set<String> setOfObjects = new HashSet<String>();
i.set("setOfObjects", setOfObjects );(i being beanshell interpreter's instance)
```

few observations :

1. keyword `Else` should be `else` (beanshell doesn't tolerate it)
2. `setOfObjects.get(index);` will throw error as there is no `get(int)` in Sets

Are you sure the `setOfObjects` which you are providing is not `null`, or with no typo error, as beanshell will assume a variable with typo error as new one. (in non strict java mode).